# Messages for users with (user.is_active =False) flag during the login process

Tags: django, django-forms, django-authentication

I am trying to add message during the log-in process , for a user who has an account, but deactivated, that he must activate it if he wants to get in.

I use LoginView controller, that uses built-in standard form called AuthenticationForm

AuthenticationForm has a following method:

```py
def confirm_login_allowed(self, user):
    """
    Controls whether the given User may log in. This is a policy setting,
    independent of end-user authentication. This default behavior is to
    allow login by active users, and reject login by inactive users.

    If the given user cannot log in, this method should raise a
    ``forms.ValidationError``.

    If the given user may log in, this method should return None.
    """
    if not user.is_active:
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            self.error_messages['inactive'],
            code='inactive',

# and list of error messages within this class

error_messages = {
    'invalid_login': _(
        "Please enter a correct %(username)s and password. Note that both "
        "fields may be case-sensitive."
    ),
    'inactive': _("This account is inactive."),
}
```

So that technically  if not user.is_active – it should show message 'inactive' but in my case for inactivated users with is_active  = False DB table  it shows the message 'invalid_login' instead.
I am trying 100% correct login and password and user is not active but it shows me 'invalid_login' message. Then I just switch on is_active flag in DB to True and it lets me in easily. 
Do you have any idea why is that could be?

Final target is to show this message  “'inactive': _("This account is inactive.")” to a user who has an account but deactivated. ( or custom message)
Technically it should work but it doesn't.
Thank you in advance and sorry in case you find this question elementary or dumb.

Tried:

```
class AuthCustomForm(AuthenticationForm):
    def clean(self):
        AuthenticationForm.clean(self)
        user = ExtraUser.objects.get(username=self.cleaned_data.get('username'))
        if not user.is_active and user:
            messages.warning(self.request, 'Please Activate your account',
                             extra_tags="", fail_silently=True)
           # return HttpResponseRedirect(' your url'))
```

FINALLY what helped:

```py
class AuthCustomForm(AuthenticationForm):

    def get_invalid_login_error(self):

        user = ExtraUser.objects.get(username=self.cleaned_data.get('username'))

        if not user.is_active and user:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['inactive'],
                code='inactive',)
        else:
            return forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['invalid_login'],
                code='invalid_login',
                params={'username': self.username_field.verbose_name},
            )
```

This is kind of wierd way to do it as DJANGO built -in code should have worked. I am not sure that i havent fixed my own mistake, made before here. perhaps i made things even worse.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*This is a long answer but hopefully it will be useful and provide some insight as to how things are working behind the scenes.*

To see why the `'inactive'` `ValidationError` isn't being raised for an inactive user, we have to start by looking at how the `LoginView` is implemented, specifically its `post` method.

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Handle POST requests: instantiate a form instance with the passed
    POST variables and then check if it's valid.
    """
    form = self.get_form()
    if form.is_valid():
        return self.form_valid(form)
    else:
        return self.form_invalid(form)
```

This method is called when the `LoginView` receives the `POST` request with the form data in it. `get_form` populates the `AuthenticationForm` with the `POST` data from the request and then the form is checked, returning a different response depending on whether it's valid or not. We're concerned with the form checking, so let's look dig into what the `is_valid` method is doing.

The [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/) do a good job of explaining how form and field validation works, so I won't go into too much detail. Basically, all that we need to know is that when the `is_valid` method of a form is called, the form first validates all of its fields individually, then calls its `clean` method to do any form-wide validation.

Here is where we need to look at how the `AuthenticationForm` is implemented, as it defines its own `clean` method.

```
def clean(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
    password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')

    if username is not None and password:
        self.user_cache = authenticate(self.request, username=username, password=password)
        if self.user_cache is None:
            raise self.get_invalid_login_error()
        else:
            self.confirm_login_allowed(self.user_cache)

    return self.cleaned_data
```

This is where the `confirm_login_allowed` method that you identified comes into play. We see that the username and password are passed to the `authenticate` function. This checks the given credentials against all of the authentication backends defined by the `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` setting (see [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#authentication-backends) for more info), returning the authenticated user's `User` model if successful and `None` if not.

The result of `authenticate` is then checked. If it's `None`, then the user could not be authenticated, and the `'invalid_login'` `ValidationError` is raised as expected. If not, then the user has been authenticated and `confirm_login_allowed` raises the `'inactive'` `ValidationError` if the user is inactive.

**So why isn't the `'inactive'` `ValidationError` raised?**

It's because the inactive user fails to authenticate, and so `authenticate` returns `None`, which means `get_invalid_login_error` is called instead of `confirm_login_allowed`.

**Why does the inactive user fail to authenticate?**

To see this, i'm going to assume that you are not using a custom authentication backend, which means that your `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` setting is set to the default: `['django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend']`. This means that `ModelBackend` is the only authentication backend being used and we can look at its `authenticate` method which is what the previously seen `authenticate` function calls internally.

```
def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
    if username is None:
        username = kwargs.get(UserModel.USERNAME_FIELD)
    if username is None or password is None:
        return
    try:
        user = UserModel._default_manager.get_by_natural_key(username)
    except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
        # Run the default password hasher once to reduce the timing
        # difference between an existing and a nonexistent user (#20760).
        UserModel().set_password(password)
    else:
        if user.check_password(password) and self.user_can_authenticate(user):
            return user
```

We're interested in the last `if` statement.

```
if user.check_password(password) and self.user_can_authenticate(user):
    return user
```

For our inactive user, we know that the password is correct, so `check_password` will return `True`. This means that it must be the `user_can_authenticate` method which is returning `False` and causing the inactive user to not be authenticated. Hold on, because we're almost there...

```
def user_can_authenticate(self, user):
    """
    Reject users with is_active=False. Custom user models that don't have
    that attribute are allowed.
    """
    is_active = getattr(user, 'is_active', None)
    return is_active or is_active is None
```

**Aha!** `user_can_authenticate` returns `False` if `user.is_active` is `False` which causes the user to not authenticate.

**The solution**

We can subclass `ModelBackend`, override `user_can_authenticate`, and point the `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` setting to this new subclass.

*app/backends.py*

```
from django.contrib.auth import backends


class CustomModelBackend(backends.ModelBackend):
    def user_can_authenticate(self, user):
        return True
```

*settings.py*

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'app.backends.CustomModelBackend',
]
```

I think this solution is cleaner than changing the logic of `get_invalid_login_error`.

You can then override the `'inactive'` `ValidationError` message by subclassing `AuthenticationForm`, overriding `error_messages`, and setting the `authentication_form` attribute of the `LoginView` to this new subclass.

```
from django.contrib.auth import forms as auth_forms, views as auth_views
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


class CustomAuthenticationForm(auth_forms.AuthenticationForm):
    error_messages = {
        'invalid_login': _(
            "Please enter a correct %(username)s and password. Note that both "
            "fields may be case-sensitive."
        ),
        'inactive': _("CUSTOM INACTIVE MESSAGE."),
    }


class LoginView(auth_views.LoginView):
    authentication_form = CustomAuthenticationForm
```

Comment: Excellent answer. There is now an `AllowAllUsersModelBackend` class in `django.contrib.auth.backends` which does the same like your `CustomModelBackend`.

Comment: I didn't know this, thanks!

Comment: Excellent answer, Is there a Django Rest Framework equivalent of such an implementation?

Answer (score 1):

```py
class AuthCustomForm(AuthenticationForm):

    def get_invalid_login_error(self):

        user = ExtraUser.objects.get(username=self.cleaned_data.get('username'))

        if not user.is_active and user:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['inactive'],
                code='inactive',)
        else:
            return forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['invalid_login'],
                code='invalid_login',
                params={'username': self.username_field.verbose_name}, )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.

```
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
if user and user.is_active==False:
   messages.warning(request, 'Please Activate your account', extra_tags="")
   return HttpResponseRedirect(' your url'))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have tried it but it doesnt work. I have updated the question with what i have tried